# dynamic operator comparison from table fields

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, **discount profile** and **transaction**

In my **discount table** I have fields :

- fields for operator (equal, greather, less, greater equeal, less equal)
- field for discount amount
- field priority

In **transaction** table I have

- transaction amount

My question is:

How to select highest priority discount profile that fulfill clause( transactionamount operator discountamount)

eg-

> profile 1: operator less than, discount amount 300, priority 1
>   profile 2: operator greater than, discount amount 500, priority 2
>   profile 3: operator greater than, discount amount 750, priority 3
>
> transaction amount: 800
>   profile match: profile 2 and profile 3
>   profile selected: profile 2

Thanks

Comment: Do u have  a query that u have tried and not working ,so that it may be easy to understand

Comment: previously, my discount profile not consist operators, so it easy to compare with trans amount:
"AND jvfee.constantAmount < Trans.amount"..
wondering if it possible to make dynamic operator comparison..